# Install libxml2 bindings for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, libxml2

### The Problem

I’m trying to build `libxml` (`libxml2-2.7.8`) bindings for Python 3.2.  When I run the following:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.2
```

The compilation of `libxml2-2.7.8` works...but the Python bindings for `libxml2-2.7.8` don’t!

### Attempted Fixes

1. Ported `setup.py` and `generator.py` (using `2to3`, and some basic patches on `generator.py`)
2. Patched `libxml.c` and `types.c` as follows:

   - replace PyInt* by PyLong*
   - replace PyString* by PyBytes*

### Current Situation

Unfortunately, it still wasn’t enough.  I ran `python3.2 setup.py build` and got the following error:

```
types.c:594:17: error: ‘PyInstanceObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I can’t find the Python3 equivalent of `PyInstanceObject`!

**Has anyone managed to compile `libxml2` bindings for Python 3?**

**Did I miss something???  Can anybody help? :(**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyInstanceObject is a part of the support for old style types, which is [gone in Python 3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/8f5b9982beba), and has been deprecated since Python 2.2. The trick here is to first update the bindings to use new-style classes, and then port to Python 3.

(Or use lxml, which wraps the libxml2 in a Pythonic XML classes).

I'm not 100% sure what the replacement is, I've never done old-style classes in C, but I think it's simply a PyObject.

Comment: you're right. the code compile but importing libxml2 from python3.2 do not work : `ImportError: ./libxml2mod.cpython-32mu.so: undefined symbol: PyFile_Check`  File object interface have change a lot and PyFile_Check is gone. I haven't found a replacement or workaround yet

Comment: PyFile_Check checks if the object is a file object. Since the rewrite of the IO layer, there is no file object. It's hard to say what you replace it with without reading the code. Usually you shouldn't need to check it, if it behaves like a file, it is a file.